# eclipselink 2 oneToMany with 1 association table , data not refreshed from DB

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have 2 table A and B 
and one association table AB

A is oneToMany to AB ,
B is oneToMany to AB,

And i closed the cache of eclipselink. using

```
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

I update A from one thread which means update A in one entityManager

And use `entityManager.find(B.class,id)`to get B and use `entityManager.refresh(B)` in order to force to read B's data from DB  in another thread (another entityManager)

but when i try to use B.getABlist() to get A's  info
the A's info is not the latest in DB

So my question is , is there anything wrong with my operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem

i forget to set the  CascadeType.REFRESH in AB entity for two ManyToOney relationships with A and B

so the refresh doesn't work